# how does the lsof command get its information on linux

Tags: linux

The `lsof` command can list open files including network connections.

I think it should works just like the other system tools which gather information from the `/proc/`, `/dev/` or `/sys` locations in the Linux filesystem.

But when I tried to find information about open files from these locations, I failed:

```
ls /proc/self/fd
ls /proc/net/tcp
ls /dev/fd/
```

How does `lsof` get this information?

Comment: You can use a strace command to see what files are read exactly.Usually such data comes from proc fs

Comment: When all else fails, read the source code for `lsof`. That would contain the definitive answers to how it finds its information.

Comment: I voted to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

I found that [this](https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/blob/master/00PORTING) lsof repository includes a guide to porting that has the following:

> Lsof obtains data about open UNIX dialect files by reading the
> kernel's proc structure information, following it to the related
> user structure, then reading the open file structures stored
> (usually) in the user structure.  Typically lsof uses the kernel
> memory devices, /dev/kmem, /dev/mem, etc. to read kernel data.

The document has quite a bit of information about how the program works.

Comment: The question is off topic and should have been closed when it was asked seven years ago. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer] Vote to close them instead.

Comment: Hi @Rob, Out of curiosity, why is this  off-topic - should the question have been asked on another site or?

Comment: @Morten Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Rob, after all these SO still has no way to migrate question to the appropriate subdomain? Wow...